# Install RHEL 6 to a remote drive (NFS root)

Tags: rhel, system-installation, nfs, kickstart

I need to be able to install RHEL 6 to a network drive. In more modern operating systems such as RHEL 7 this is an option. Unfortunately for me I have to use RHEL 6 (actually Scientific Linux 6.6 which is Red Hat 6 based). I plan on running a kickstart script to do the install silently, and I can script any bash or python before the install starts to mount my NSF drive I plan to use for the root file system.

The problem is I'm unsure of how to point the install at a local mounted directory instead of a hard drive. Anyone have any advice or know how?

If this is unclear I'll update with more information, but I think this is enough to grasp what I am trying to do.

Comment: I don't think that's how it is done, see e.g. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-disklesssystems.html - but I've never done this myself, so wait for further advice.

Comment: @Mat - After reading through that section of the manual, you do seem correct. It is frustrating that RH6 can not do NFS root when platforms like SLES11 can.